# HTML5 Canvas in SVG element with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-canvas, jquery-svg

I need to insert a canvas into an SVG element. I need a canvas in SVG because I am using d3js which uses SVG and jquery sparklines which creates a canvas. Is there any way to make the sparklines graph part of the svg element? I tried to draw a graph with sparklines in SVG but returns a c.innerHTML is undefined.

Thanks!

Comment: Use `<foreignElement>` to create an XHTML `<body>` in the SVG and then add a `<canvas>` to that. Alternatively, embed your SVG in X/HTML, and [find the locations of SVG elements in HTML coordinates](http://phrogz.net/svg/html_location_in_svg_2.svg) so that you can absolutely-position a `<canvas>` from the main HTML along with the SVG.

Comment: I'm impressed that this was enough information for you to go on; I assumed it wouldn't, and so didn't put it as a full answer. Glad to have helped :)

Comment: Hey @Phrogz the solution works in firefox 13 but not firefox 4 or the latest chrome and safari. I was looking at the firebug logs and the opening div tag is not being created. Do have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer to Phrogz comment below the question. I am just putting it as the answer to close the thread. The answer to my problem was that I needed a  element in my SVG to put place a html tag such as a div. The div was required for the canvas that sparkline generates.

So I just had to add this

```
svgObj.append("foreignObject")
  .attr("width", "20")
  .attr("height", "20")
  .append("xhtml:div");
```

Then for sparkline I just pointed it to the foreign object's div and now I have a canvas in a SVG :)

Thanks Progz!